# Why width settings doesn't work on ie11?

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an single page application with angular js. There is left menu on page and I can hide this menu by pressing "hide" button. Left menu container:

```
<div ng-class="{'filterLeftHidden': !vm.isFiltersPaneShown}">...</div>

.filterLeftHidden {
    width: 0 !important;
}
```

When I am pressing button in chrome/firefox it is working good. When I am doing the same in ie11 it doesn't.

In ie11 developer tools I can see this computed values:

[image]

Why element width is 302.4px if I already set it to 0?

Comment: Good question, but it'll be difficult to troubleshoot based on what you've provided. What happens if you disable the statement for `.vpm-view--has-sid`?

Comment: Instead of a width of 0px, can you use display: none for hiding the filter?

Comment: The `display:table-cell` might be a clue to the problem; table cells usually take `width` to mean `min-width`. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/m3rvfLmv/). In fact, with this fiddle, none of the browsers display it at width 0. So we need to see more context.